# How to call different functions in PHP file from iPhone App?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

Now I have a app to get some data from php file in web server. and this php file have some some functions with get diffierent results with db, and I found that the objective_c can only call the php file and not to call the functions in php, and maybe I am wrong , but how to get the functions of one php file, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talking about PHP, that's not how it works, 
function test($arg1, $arg2) is correct, but you need to explicitly call the test function from with ur php

example:

```
> function test($arg1,$arg2){ //DO some
> stuff }
> 
> $arg1=$_REQUEST['arg1']; //This is
> where u grab the values from the URL
> $arg2=$_REQUEST['arg2'];
> 
> //Then call your function
> 
> test($arg1,$arg2);
```

So when u called this script with NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/myphp.php?test&arg1=%@&arg2=%@",@"arg1",@"arg2"];  the php script should work and return whatever is done inside test() function.

Comment: By the way look up for ASIHTTPREQUEST to make requests to your php scripts

Comment: thk you very much! I'll research the ASIHTTPREQUEST!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. You can send a POST or GET variable in your iPhone HTTP call and use that with a switch on the PHP end to get a function name. That is kind of a pain.

You can use rewriting. [HTAccess Info](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php). Which is a bigger pain.

Or you can use a framework that has URI routing built-in. I generally use [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). Check out the [routing info.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) This would be my recommendation.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know it very well. and if the php function is :
function test($arg1, $arg2) {...}
and my url will be: NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/myphp.php?test&arg1=%@&arg2=%@",@"arg1",@"arg2"];

Comment: Look into using codeIgniter. Read the documentation. I think this is the best option for you. As for that URL string, no. You are passing information as a get, but access it as data passed when the function is called. In order to access data as you have written it you need to use $_GET. Google $_GET and PHP and you will have the info you need.